# Problems with the site.master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

How to change the length of the the nav-bar of site.master. As the number of items on the top bar increase the page over shadowing the content below.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
                      data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Naveen's Web Application</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper code sample.

Comment: Here's my site.master nav_bar code, link to the website where you could see the problem. http://omisapps.niu.edu/z1758517/ProjLogin

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

Comment: Play with the css stylesheet where navbar is defined, you should be able to extend the width. You're getting this overlap effect, because you have too many buttons on top, and they already don't fit, so the navbar becomes thiker.

Comment: How to I extend the nav_bar width to fit in all the button?

Comment: Please edit your question and add code there instead of posting it as comments.

Comment: Added the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

Find the following in your CSS files and increase the three widths until it looks right. And please fix your question with proper formatting and code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Which one of those three allows me to have more buttons on top of the bar.